# Fully removing raster values that have been masked out

Tags: arcgis-pro, masking

I want to fully delete the values to this suitability raster that have been masked out. When I apply the mask (feature layer -> appearance -> masking) the stretch does not rescale. It is basically like just turning on the vector mask layer over the suitability raster (Weighte_Sum_2). Any ideas? I have already tried messing with the symbology of the Weighte_Sum_2 layer but it is acting like those values masked out values are still there.

[image: Without masking applied]

[image: With masking applied]

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/set-null.htm

Comment: The answer can be found here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94834/remove-or-setnull-areas-of-overlapping-rasters-using-arcgis-desktop